# How to sort the a list in C# for data "Test Test test test test" in similar way as of SQL

Tags: list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list and compare it with sorting applied on UI(which is same as happening in SQL Db)
I am using below function to verify the same

1)

```
orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => (string)x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
2) orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => (string)x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

For the 2nd output is

```
Test
Test
test
test
test
```

Whereas, the SQL sorts the data as

```
Test
test
test
test
Test
```

Hence,My comparison is failing.

Comment: what is the order you are following on sql side? here you are using descending whose result is fine

Comment: If you are using SQL  then use COLLATE  like SELECT myString  FROM tblString ORDER BY COLLATE myString ASC